# Nested dictionary parsing error JSON- TypeError: string indices must be integers

Tags: python, json, pandas, dictionary, key-value

[Image of Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XAt7m.png)

Im trying to pull the key values pair for the dictionary associated to the "awayBattingTotals". However, im encountering the below error that i do not know how to fix.

Snippet of the JSON response is below

```
{
  'namefield': '9 Lopez, N  SS',
  'ab': '3',
  'r': '0',
  'h': '1',
  'doubles': '0',
  'triples': '0',
  'hr': '0',
  'rbi': '0',
  'sb': '0',
  'bb': '0',
  'k': '0',
  'lob': '2',
  'avg': '.248',
  'ops': '.599',
  'personId': 670032,
  'battingOrder': '900',
  'substitution': False,
  'note': '',
  'name': 'Lopez, N',
  'position': 'SS',
  'obp': '.305',
  'slg': '.294'
}],
'awayBattingTotals': {
  'namefield': 'Totals',
  'ab': '33',
  'r': '2',
  'h': '7',
  'hr': '1',
  'rbi': '2',
  'bb': '0',
  'k': '8',
  'lob': '13',
  'avg': '',
  'ops': '',
  'obp': '',
  'slg': '',
  'name': 'Totals',
  'position': '',
  'note': '',
  'substitution': False,
  'battingOrder': '',
  'personId': 0
},
'homeBattingTotals': {
  'namefield': 'Totals',
  'ab': '34',
  'r': '4',
  'h': '9',
  'hr': '2',
  'rbi': '4',
  'bb': '1',
  'k': '7',
  'lob': '13',
  'avg': '',
  'ops': '',
  'obp': '',
  'slg': '',
  'name': 'Totals',
  'position': '',
  'note': '',
  'substitution': False,
  'battingOrder': '',
  'personId': 0
},
```

The below is obtained via
`statsapi.boxscore_data(662647)`

`summary = statsapi.boxscore(662647)`

From the above im trying to run

```
summary["awayBattingTotals"]["Totals"]
```

to pull the below values:

```
`awayBattingTotals': {'namefield': 'Totals',   'ab': '33',   'r': '2',   'h': '7',   'hr': '1',   'rbi': '2',   'bb': '0',   'k': '8',   'lob': '13',`
```

but i keep getting the below error:

> TypeError: string indices must be integers`

Comment: You have `]` without a matching `[`

Comment: It sounds like you never parsed the JSON to a dictionary. Use `json.loads()`.

Comment: What does this have to do with pandas?

Comment: the json response is just a snippet from the full response.. `statsapi.boxscore_data(662647)`. 

So i cant run the `json.loads()`. Im using pandas to write the info into a df

Comment: Why can't you use `json.loads()`?  It's clearly JSON.

Comment: i get the below error. 
`JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`

Comment: also im not a pro by any means, so im just looking for whatever help i can get

Comment: That error usually means that the data you're trying to decode is empty.

Comment: What you showed isn't actually JSON, since JSON uses double quotes, not single quotes. Is that a snippet of the decoded JSON? Or is the string actually in that format?

Comment: Please show your code that gets the JSON and tries to extract from it.

Comment: The error you're getting means that either `summary` or `summary["awayBattingTotals"]` is a string, not a dictionary.

Comment: Please post code, data, and results as text, not screenshots. http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: Code added! 
using `statsapi.boxscore_data(662647)` gives me a huge nested dictionary 

out of which i try to run 
`summary = statsapi.boxscore(662647)` 
`summary["awayBattingTotals"]["totals"]` which gives me an error

TypeError: string indices must be integers.

What im trying to pull is 
`awayBattingTotals': {'namefield': 'Totals',   'ab': '33',   'r': '2',   'h': '7',   'hr': '1',   'rbi': '2',   'bb': '0',   'k': '8',   'lob': '13',``

Answer (score 0):

As Barmar mentioned, it seemed like the data wasn't behaving as json...

Switching the single to double quotes in the json-like text of the response allows me to reach into it with json.loads() like so:

```
mysecond = '''{"awayBattingTotals": {"namefield": "Totals", "ab": "33", "r": "2"}}'''
    
myload = json.loads(mysecond)
print myload
```

Result:

```
{u'awayBattingTotals': {u'r': u'2', u'ab': u'33', u'namefield': u'Totals'}}
```

This failed in the same way you described when I cut and pasted the json response you included in your question:

```
import json

myjson = """{'awayBattingTotals': { 'namefield': 'Totals',
      'ab': '33',
      'r': '2'}}"""

print json.loads(myjson)
```

result:
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str

Comment: i converted the whole response into a JSON format... but im still unable to pull the awayBattingTotals from the response in the code

Comment: Try adding a debug print prior to diving into it additional layers. When you have the deepest layer you can get to before erroring, print its type: `type(variableName)`